# GatewayTimeout Exception when Accessing Google Cloud DataStore in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am following the guide for using Datastore in python found here: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries

When I go to use the put() method, there is a long pause, and a google.cloud.exceptions.GatewayTimeout: 504 Deadline Exceeded is returned.

I'm attempting to follow the guide in the python shell. I'm not sure what to do from here or how to resolve this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.